# Collect Entities in autoCAD drawing and change the colors

Tags: vba, autocad, cad

[The code i tried line collection under entity collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeTZs.png)I want to change the colors / layers of different linetypes (continuous / dashed/ center) in autocad drawing using VBA. I tried to collect all the entities and filter them! but no success!

Comment: As your question is pretty short you might also add more information and the code that is the problem - the more you explain the easier it is for others to help you. Good luck!

Comment: Surely i'll, Thanks!

Comment: Links to pictures of code on another site are useless. Can you not copy and paste?

Comment: @msw Hey! I am new to community, i didn't know that. But then i realized the link was created by the site automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotcha! Instead of collecting linetypes i had to use Iacadline2 and then filter based on names. 
Code works fine now.